# import json to pydantic model, change fiield name

Tags: python, json, pydantic

I have json, from external system, with fields like 'system-ip', 'domain-id'. those name are not allowed in python, so i want to change them to 'system_ip', 'domain_id' etc.
I read all on stackoverflow with 'pydantic' w keywords, i tried examples from pydantic docs, as a last resort i generated json schema from my json, and then with

`datamodel-codegen --input device_schema.json --output model.py`

i generated model.

generated model has fields like

```
    system_ip: str = Field(..., alias='system-ip')
    host_name: str = Field(..., alias='host-name')
    device_type: str = Field(..., alias='device-type')
    device_groups: List[str] = Field(..., alias='device-groups')
```

and it still doesn't work . when i do

```
with open("device.json") as file:
    raw_device = json.load(file)
d = PydanticDevice(**raw_device)
```

pydantic still sees the 'old' field names, not the annotated, and i have error

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'system-ip'
```

What i do wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

so, for future reference, decorator @pydantic.dataclass doesn't do the same thing as inherit from pydantic BaseModel

```
@dataclasses
class VmanageDevice:
    deviceId: str
    system_ip: str = Field(..., alias='system-ip')
    host_name: str = Field(..., alias='host-name')
...
```

doesn't work

but

```
class VmanageDevice(BaseModel):
    deviceId: str
    system_ip: str = Field(..., alias='system-ip')
    host_name: str = Field(..., alias='host-name')
    reachability: str
...
```

works as charm

Comment: Go ahead and accept this answer if it worked for you!

Comment: What if the json data you want is multiple levels down? ie:  you want host-name but it is located `{host:{ details:{host_name: the_host}}}`?